# How hyperledger fabric works in private block chains?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new to block chain and learning from past few weeks about block chain but until now I have many times heard about hyper ledger fabric but never found a good documentation for a begginer.

Comment: Official documentation is pretty good. I also started Hyperledger from couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, the official documentation is quite good and it will definitely be helpful for a beginner. I have used this documentation to create and run blockchain networks on MacBooks and laptops running on Ubuntu. I have no experience of running Hyperledger on a Windows machine. If you have a Windows machine, create a dual boot so that you can use Ubuntu for your Hyperledger work.

Use the tutorials provided as part of the Hyperledger download. They do work as long as all of the pre-requisites are satisified. The test-network tutorial is quite good as it starts you off with building a 2-peer network.

If you use Visual Studio Code, there is an IBM extension that you can use as well. I'm not sure if it has advanced beyond version 1.4 yet, but it will help you to get a single peer network up and running quickly so that you can concentrate on perhaps developing some contract code. YouTube is a great source for Hyperledger tutorial videos which should be quite helpful.

Best of luck.